# Set Location Counter to a new value in linker script

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, linker, ld, linker-scripts

I'm confused about the location counter, especially when setting it to
a new value in the output section.

I write a simple program and a linker script to make my question more
clear. The code is as follows:

**test.s**

```
section .text
        .globl _start
_start:
        movq $1, %rax
        movq $0, %rbx
        int $0x80
```

**test.lds**

```
SECTIONS
{
        . = 0x10;
        label_1 = .;
        custom_section : {
                . = 0x20;
                label_2 = . ;
                label_3 = ABSOLUTE(.) ;
                *(.text) ;
        }
}
```

After linking, use `nm` command to print symbol addresses:

```
0000000000000010 T label_1
0000000000000030 T label_2
0000000000000030 A label_3
0000000000000030 T _start
```

I can't understand why `lable_2` is `0x30`. As the [LD documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.30/ld/Location-Counter.html#Location-Counter)
says, if `.` is used inside a section description, it refers to the
byte offset from the start of that section, not an absolute address.
In the `custom_section`, `.` is set to `0x20` which is a relative offset,
so I think `label_2` should also be `0x20`. The value of `label_3` is
reasonable because it's an absolute address.

Could someone please explain why `label_2` is 0x30? Thanks!

Comment: custom_section starts at VMA 0x10 because of the `. = 0x10` . `. = 0x20` is 0x20 relative to the start of the section it is in which is 0x10 so it advanced the VMA to 0x30.

Comment: Are the `.` in `. = 0x10` and `. = 0x20` two different variables?

Comment: No, they are the same but how the location counter assignments are interpreted is different based on whether it appears in a section or outside one.

Comment: But, `. = 0x20` and `label_2 = .` are also interpreted differently because `label_2` is `0x30` which is an absolute address.

Comment: I believe that the statement _If . is used inside a section description however, it refers to the byte offset from the start of that section, not an absolute address._ is within the context of setting the location counter with `.=`

Comment: @MichaelPetch So, in the statement `a = 0x20`, `a` is relative to the start of `custom_section` while in the statement `label_2 = a`, `a` is relative to the start of SECTIONS statement. It seems this is the only explanation for now.